# Fill array using odbc adapter with out loop

Tags: arrays, fill

Please help me to load array value from database using odbc adapter with out using loop statement.

Thanks,

S.Somu

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a language, here's an example in Python using mxODBC:

```
import mx.ODBC.unixODBC as mx
db = mx.DriverConnect('DSN=[your DSN here]')
c = db.cursor()
results = c.execute("SELECT * from tableName").fetchall()
```

If you have more detail - such as a specific language, you might get an answer closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks Sir .Is possible in vb.net?